# How to make protobuf-net callbacks work by programmatically set it up?

Tags: c#, callback, protobuf-net

If I setup protobuf programmatically like this:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(BaseClass), true);
```

the following callback never get called:

```
class BaseClass
{
    [OnSerializing]
    public void BeforeSerialization()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BeforeSerialization");
    }
}
```

However, if I add attribute "[ProtoContract]" to "BaseClass", then the callback is called.
I thought everything specified through Protobuf attributes can also be done programmatically. Did I miss some calls or steps?

Comment: Are you compiling the model after adding the type?

Comment: Yes, I call RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CompileInPlace()

Answer (score 0):

The `OnSerializingAttribute` etc are only processed for things that it already believes are data-contracts/proto-contracts. If you're doing everything manually:

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(BaseClass), false)
    .SetCallbacks(
        beforeSerialize: nameof(BaseClass.BeforeSerialization),
        afterSerialize: null,
        beforeDeserialize: null,
        afterDeserialize: null);
```